# Passing Google app engine custom models via intent in android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-intent

I have a GAE backend and an Android client. I have generated the client library successfully and that works fine. Now, I'm trying to send an object via an intent from one activity to another in Android. To my horror I noticed that the generated GAE models are final classes that don't implement parcelable or serializable interfaces. Because of that I decided to try and use gson to parse them to json string and then back to the original object. That however fails on fields like DateTime for some reason. My next try was to just let the classes implement serializable (bad idea to touch generated classes!!) but the issue with that was that since these classes extend AbstractMap the serializable output is a HashMap rather than my original object! Now I'm thinking about letting it implement Parcelable but that's a lot of work and sounds like a very bad idea since these models are generated and could change (thus removing my parcelable work.)

I know that people here love code so here is my problem written in code:
Activity A (MainActivity) is trying to send a "UserScore" object (generated from GAE) to activity B.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ResultsActivity.BUNDLE_USERSCORE, userScore);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_COUNTDOWN);
```

This would've given my error since userScore isn't parcelable or serializable but in this case I made it serializable. Activity B (ResultsActivity) receives:

```
Object extra = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(BUNDLE_USERSCORE);
```

Now you would expect the extra object to be of the type UserScore but since it was sent via intent and is a subclass of AbstractMap it is in fact a HashMap.

So, my question is: has anybody encountered this issue and found a way to properly send GAE models via intents in android?